# Select não retorna nada quando tenho NULL na chave estrangeira

Tags: mysql

Tabela COMPROVANTE: codigo, subprojetocodigo
Tabela SUBPROJETO: codigo, nome

meu select:

```
select a.codigo, q.nome as nomesubprojeto, a.subprojeto from comprovante a, subprojeto q where a.subprojeto = q.codigo and a.codigo = 3
```

funciona normalmente quando no campo subprojetocodigo eu tenho algo cadastrado
mas alguns desses campos são NULL

quando eu dou aquele select e a chave estrangeira é null, não retorna nada

como eu faria para retornar mas dizendo que nomesuprojeto é null?

Comment: Por que não usar INNER JOIN ou LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Você quer fazer um `LEFT OUTTER JOIN` mas está fazendo um `INNER JOIN` implicito. Existe uma notação p/ fazer isso implicitamente mas é muito melhor vc já ir se acostumando a escrever SQL em notação explícita

Answer (score 2):

Da maneira como montou seu `SELECT` você está fazendo um `INNER JOIN`.

Substitua por um `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.codigo, q.nome as nomesubprojeto, a.subprojeto 
FROM comprovante a LEFT OUTER JOIN subprojeto q ON a.subprojeto = q.codigo 
WHERE a.codigo = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza algo assim:

```
SELECT a.codigo, 
    ISNULL(q.nome, '') AS nomesubprojeto, 
    a.subprojeto 
FROM comprovante a 
    LEFT JOIN subprojeto q ON a.subprojeto = q.codigo 
WHERE a.codigo = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Não tem segredo nenhum - a linguagem SQL foi feita para parecer inglês e só seguindo a lógica do seu "where" fica fácil entender que não vai ter nenhum registro para o qual o "a.subprojeto" seja NULL e que tenha um equivalente "NULL" em q.código. Esta query deve funcionar:

```
select a.codigo, q.nome as nomesubprojeto, a.subprojeto from 
     comprovante a, subprojeto q 
where (a.subprojeto = q.codigo OR a.subprojeto IS NULL) AND a.codigo = 3
```

Uma forma mais específica, e que vai ser bem mais famíliar para quem já está acostumado com SQL é usar a clausula intermediária de "join" para indicar a junção de tabelas antes da cláusula "where". No caso, como você quer resultados da tabela da esquerda mesmo quando não houver um registro correspondente, o correto é o `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.codigo, q.nome as nomesubprojeto, a.subprojeto
     FROM comprovante as a  
     LEFT JOIN subprojeto as q 
     ON a.subprojeto = q.codigo 
where a.codigo = 3
```

Comment: eu preciso de algo assim pq na verdade minha query é gigante, coloquei só um pedacinho.
preciso só de uma linha, como esse exemplo: where (a.subprojeto = q.codigo OR a.subprojeto IS NULL)

só que nesse exemplo, ele me retornou todos os subprojetos, daí na hora de exibir o nomesuprojeto, ao invés de retornar null ele exibe o primeiro da lista

Comment: com o LEFT JOIN, o nomesubprojeto deve ser simplesmente "NULL".